# How to send data to webpage html

Tags: javascript, android, html, json

I have one app  .When click submit ==> my webpage will show result .But i don't know use javascript json.anyone help me.thank you very much

Sorry.I have litte Eng..so..

==>It my app android
[image]

==>It's my webpage (image and code)
[image]

```
 <html>
<head>
        <script>
 function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myid").value=$ab;

 }
</script
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunction()">
        <input id="myid"  type="text" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Code java (my app)

```
public class ChennaiIntent extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText value;
private Button btn;
private ProgressBar pb;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

        // out of range
        Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());
    }


}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://11.10.88.2/tuan/example.html");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Where in your page is the text to appear?  Add a div with an id and then update that ...